# Get selected item of bootstrap dropdown with Angular4

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm building dynamically a dropdown bootstrap component like :

```
<div class="dropdown" >
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Selectionner un filtre...<span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" >
    <li *ngFor="let v of items" (click) = "onSelect($event);">      <-- ??????

      <a class="dropdown-item"  href="#">{{ v.val }}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How can I get the index of the selected item with my onSelect() function ?
($event is MouseEvent structure)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare an index in ngFor:

```
<li *ngFor="let v of items; let i = index" (click) = "onSelect($event, i);">   
  <a class="dropdown-item"  href="#">{{ v.val }}</a>
</li>
```